# similarity between two vectors representing star graphs

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

this is a bit algorithmic and I'm not sure if it's fit correctly under SO, let me know if it doesn't.

I want to implement some kind of distance or similarity function between two labeled star-graphs. For example I can have the following to graph representations:

```
A = [3 -1   0;
     4  1   0;
     2  0   1;
     2  0  -1]
```

and

```
B = [3 -0.8   1
     4  1.4   0.4;
     2  0.1   1.9]
```

My idea (which is actually based mostly on a [paper](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~boiman/publications/boiman_irani_detecting_irregularities.pdf) I'm reading) is to perform some kind of belief propagation: Let's say that A is the observed graph - each row is a neighbor of a central node, the first column is the label, the second is the x position and the third one is the y position (positions are relative to the central node). B is a graph in out database, and I want to see how close or similar they are.

In the paper they are calculating the likelihood for the observed graph A given B as the product of the likelihoods for all the nodes. How would you implement this efficiently in matlab?

I would appreciate any thought or inspiration, I'm not looking for a code to solve it, I just want to learn from you masters how would you approach this problem.

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had only a cursory look at that paper, I think what you are looking for is an algorithm for inference in Bayesian networks. There are notoriously computationally expensive and hard to implement, so I do recommend looking for ready-made solutions. Google returns plenty of hits for "matlab graphical models"

--  EDIT --

The website posted in one of the comments looks quite detailed, but may be slightly outdated (2005).  I'd like to recommend a different piece of software.
I have been using [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) for a while and I find it quite OK. The authors are really well known in the NLP community. Turns out there is an extension that allows for arbitrary graphical structure- [GRMM](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/grmm/index.php). Written in Java, open-source. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I found [this great site](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnsoft.html) for comparing dozens of packages, I think it's a good place to start.

Comment: I started reading the documentation of MALLET and GRMM and it looks promising. Thanks. I'll update this question after solving it so it will help others in the future.

Comment: Please help me with mallet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113228/how-can-we-create-custom-template-using-grmm-inbuilt-class-in-mallet