# How can we create custom template using grmm inbuilt class in mallet?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am new to mallet and currently working on Sparql query optimization using template based model. For this i wanted to create a template model from RDf graph. The three templates which i want to create is class, attribute and relation. i have come across this tool called mallet which can help me to create a template. but still i am not getting an idea how can i do so using ACRF.Template in grmm.Can someone please give me guidelines about the template creation using mallet.[image: My rdf graph]
See the below image. I want a (1) class template for example movie all entities belonging to movie are included. (2) an attribute template suppose attribute edge "title" in which all entities belonging to that title are include. (3) Relation template which have source and target relation for example "Spouse".

My Use case:
1) I want a Bayesian Network model using Template(Predefine Class is available in Mallet).
2) fire a sparql query on that Model.

Can any one help me reach my goal?

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26791/how-can-we-create-custom-template-using-grmm-inbuilt-class-in-mallet

Comment: I know its a duplicate but that user is working along with me and we both want the answer, which is still not availbale :(

Comment: I am not familiar with mallet, but from what I can find it's an NLP library. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're after? Perhaps you should also show code that you have sofar, to make it more clear what it is you're after.

Comment: `Mallet` is a NLP library and is not useful for your use case. The kinds of graphs it deals with are factor graphs (in the sense of Bayesian graphical models), not with ontological information.